# Problems after disabing lightdm

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, lightdm

I've Xubuntu 20.04, I wanted to set log in in terminal and then going to
Xfce. So I've done: "systemctl disable lightdm". Reboot and indeed log
in terminal, but startx didn't start, had to do 'startxfce4', desktop
looked kinda difference, fonts more blurry I could describe, also after
switching terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and back to Xfce4 touchpad in my laptop
stoped working, just the buttons worked.
So I tought I go back to lightdm.
sudo systemctl enable lightdm  showed me a notice:

```
Synchronizing state of lightdm.service with SysV service script with
/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lightdm
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=,
Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for
template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

 Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
 • A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another
 unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
   • A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit
   which has
     a requirement dependency on it.
     • A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path,
     timer,
       D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
       • In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with
       some
         instance name specified.
```

With quick googling I've found I should do:
sudo systemctl unmask lightdm and then sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
I've done so, but still same.
Also what I've noticed after all of this, when tried run newsgroup
client slrn I had to set up again News enfironment althoght I've it set
in .profile.

Any solution for this?

--
Thanks

Comment: Try `systemctl enable lightdm`